# Dojo number rounding AND decimal places for NumberTextBox / NumberSpinner

Tags: dojo, rounding, decimal-precision

I would like to have a *NumberSpinner* and/or *NumberTextBox* be able to do two things:

1. Display a value with a precision of **1** decimal place.
2. Round those values to the **.5**

I would also like it if the rounding occured while typing or at the minimum when the textbox loses focus. If I attempt to type `5.2` it will round to `5.0`. If I type `6.345` it will round to `6.5`.

I've attempted a wild mixture of values using `places`, `pattern` and `round` properties on both the `constraints` and/or `editOptions` objects. Nothing works.

**Notes:**

- As for a NumberSpinner I set `smallDelta` to `0.5` and it will increment property when using the spinner arrows.
- From what I understand the `places` property will override any `pattern` property you've set.
- I have yet to get rounding to work.
- According to the source documentation for `dojo/number` I should be able to use a pattern based on [these guidelines](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Number_Format_Patterns) to round with. I've tried various versions of `#.50##` with no success. It seems to add `50` to the inputed value with no rounding. Maybe I'm not getting it?
- I see the default `editOptions` `pattern` value is `#.#####` but when the textbox loses focus it rounds to three decimal places. So something else is overriding that pattern?
- Digging through some of the Dijit code it looks like the `round()` method of `dojo/number` is not being passed the an `increment` parameter in `NumberTextBox.js` in the `filter()` method. So setting `round` as a property of one of the two config objects above does nothing at all?

Here is a basic [jsFiddle using NumberSpinner](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/3hcq9983/) that attempts some rounding and decimal precision.

One of my attempts:

```html
<input 
  id="test" 
  type="text"
  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" 
  data-dojo-props="
    value: 5,
    smallDelta: 0.5,
    constraints: { min: 5, max: 1000, places: 1, round: 5 },
    editOptions: {
      places: 1
    }
    ">
```

I'm sure I can get by with extending a method on `NumberTextBox` or `NumberSpinner` like `filter()` via a custom mixin but would prefere to do it through config options on `data-dojo-props` if at all possible.

Like with a lot of Dojo somethings aren't as apparent or easy as they seem they would be, especially with Dijits. An there's just not a lot of info out there on some of the Dijits and the documentation loves to gloss over things and has always been a huge weak point of dojo.

Can anyone help clarify any of this for me. I feel like I am close and need someone to point out what I'm mostlikely overlooking. I would simply like to round a value to the nearest **.5** and/or display a single decimal place that is rounded.

Answer (score 1):

I believe rounding is deprecated in dojo or at least not supported but they really do need to update their manuals. See [here](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/7930). I took a look into this a while back and couldn't figure out a good solution with just using constraints or aspect and rounding before/after. The big problem is that if you set "places" to be 1, then a single digit input like "7" will resolve as NaN because it does not have 1 decimal place. I ended up just extending the NumberSpinner (mainly just the "parse" function) by doing some pre-processing. I know it's not what you wanted to do but looking at the dojo tickets, I don't think there's been much movement on the whole rounding front for dojo.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's good to hear from other people trying to do similar things and how they've managed things in Dojo. I was beginning to think that a custom Number Spinner was going to be in the works for myself also.